# pgAdmin is extremely slow on any remote operation

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, performance, pgadmin, postgresql-performance

I run this query from my local pgAdmin connecting remotely to our dev server:

`select * from users order by random() limit 1;`

it hangs for **17** seconds and shows

```
Total query runtime: 148 ms. 
1 row retrieved.
```

it also hangs on any operation: even right clicking on a table.

Afterwise I connect via RDP and run the same query there in the same pgAdmin version which displays results immediately with `query time: 32 ms`.

Then I run query from my local pgAdmin again:

```
Total query runtime: 337 ms.
1 row retrieved.
```

I have ping 130 ms to the server. The connection speed should be more than enough because I can upload files via FTP there pretty fast.

The same query when run with my local psql finishes in a few seconds with connection time included.

The same query in my local pgAdmin with my local db copy finishes also immediately.

pgAdmin version is 1.20.0. Checked also on the latest 1.22 - still the same.

What can I do to speed up pgAdmin?

Please note that psql works fine, I don't see the same latencies there.

pgAdmin log for 17 seconds query run:

```
2016-02-06 16:18:03 INFO   : queueing : select * from users order by random() limit 1;
2016-02-06 16:18:03 QUERY  : Thread executing query (1:server): select * from users order by random() limit 1;
2016-02-06 16:18:03 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,-1) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 23
2016-02-06 16:18:03 QUERY  : Query result: integer
2016-02-06 16:18:03 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=23
2016-02-06 16:18:03 QUERY  : Query result: 23
2016-02-06 16:18:03 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,259) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 1043
2016-02-06 16:18:03 QUERY  : Query result: character varying(255)
2016-02-06 16:18:03 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=1043
2016-02-06 16:18:03 QUERY  : Query result: 1043
2016-02-06 16:18:03 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,259) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 1043
2016-02-06 16:18:03 QUERY  : Query result: character varying(255)
2016-02-06 16:18:03 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=1043
2016-02-06 16:18:03 QUERY  : Query result: 1043
2016-02-06 16:18:03 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,-1) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 23
2016-02-06 16:18:04 QUERY  : Query result: integer
2016-02-06 16:18:04 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=23
2016-02-06 16:18:04 QUERY  : Query result: 23
2016-02-06 16:18:04 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,-1) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 23
2016-02-06 16:18:04 QUERY  : Query result: integer
2016-02-06 16:18:04 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=23
2016-02-06 16:18:04 QUERY  : Query result: 23
2016-02-06 16:18:04 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,-1) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 1114
2016-02-06 16:18:04 QUERY  : Query result: timestamp without time zone
2016-02-06 16:18:04 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=1114
2016-02-06 16:18:04 QUERY  : Query result: 1114
2016-02-06 16:18:04 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,0) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 1114
2016-02-06 16:18:04 QUERY  : Query result: timestamp(0) without time zone
2016-02-06 16:18:04 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=1114
2016-02-06 16:18:04 QUERY  : Query result: 1114
2016-02-06 16:18:04 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,-1) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 23
2016-02-06 16:18:05 QUERY  : Query result: integer
2016-02-06 16:18:05 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=23
2016-02-06 16:18:06 QUERY  : Query result: 23
2016-02-06 16:18:06 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,-1) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 23
2016-02-06 16:18:06 QUERY  : Query result: integer
2016-02-06 16:18:06 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=23
2016-02-06 16:18:06 QUERY  : Query result: 23
2016-02-06 16:18:06 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,-1) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 23
2016-02-06 16:18:07 QUERY  : Query result: integer
2016-02-06 16:18:07 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=23
2016-02-06 16:18:07 QUERY  : Query result: 23
2016-02-06 16:18:07 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,-1) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 16
2016-02-06 16:18:07 QUERY  : Query result: boolean
2016-02-06 16:18:07 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=16
2016-02-06 16:18:07 QUERY  : Query result: 16
2016-02-06 16:18:07 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,-1) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 20
2016-02-06 16:18:07 QUERY  : Query result: bigint
2016-02-06 16:18:07 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=20
2016-02-06 16:18:07 QUERY  : Query result: 20
2016-02-06 16:18:07 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,259) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 1043
2016-02-06 16:18:07 QUERY  : Query result: character varying(255)
2016-02-06 16:18:07 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=1043
2016-02-06 16:18:08 QUERY  : Query result: 1043
2016-02-06 16:18:08 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,259) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 1043
2016-02-06 16:18:08 QUERY  : Query result: character varying(255)
2016-02-06 16:18:08 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=1043
2016-02-06 16:18:08 QUERY  : Query result: 1043
2016-02-06 16:18:08 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,-1) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 1114
2016-02-06 16:18:08 QUERY  : Query result: timestamp without time zone
2016-02-06 16:18:08 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=1114
2016-02-06 16:18:08 QUERY  : Query result: 1114
2016-02-06 16:18:08 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,-1) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 23
2016-02-06 16:18:08 QUERY  : Query result: integer
2016-02-06 16:18:08 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=23
2016-02-06 16:18:08 QUERY  : Query result: 23
2016-02-06 16:18:08 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,-1) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 23
2016-02-06 16:18:09 QUERY  : Query result: integer
2016-02-06 16:18:09 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=23
2016-02-06 16:18:09 QUERY  : Query result: 23
2016-02-06 16:18:09 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,-1) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 16
2016-02-06 16:18:09 QUERY  : Query result: boolean
2016-02-06 16:18:09 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=16
2016-02-06 16:18:09 QUERY  : Query result: 16
2016-02-06 16:18:09 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,-1) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 23
2016-02-06 16:18:09 QUERY  : Query result: integer
2016-02-06 16:18:09 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=23
2016-02-06 16:18:09 QUERY  : Query result: 23
2016-02-06 16:18:09 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,-1) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 23
2016-02-06 16:18:09 QUERY  : Query result: integer
2016-02-06 16:18:09 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=23
2016-02-06 16:18:09 QUERY  : Query result: 23
2016-02-06 16:18:09 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,-1) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 16
2016-02-06 16:18:10 QUERY  : Query result: boolean
2016-02-06 16:18:10 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=16
2016-02-06 16:18:10 QUERY  : Query result: 16
2016-02-06 16:18:10 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,259) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 1043
2016-02-06 16:18:10 QUERY  : Query result: character varying(255)
2016-02-06 16:18:10 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=1043
2016-02-06 16:18:10 QUERY  : Query result: 1043
2016-02-06 16:18:11 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,259) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 1043
2016-02-06 16:18:11 QUERY  : Query result: character varying(255)
2016-02-06 16:18:11 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=1043
2016-02-06 16:18:11 QUERY  : Query result: 1043
2016-02-06 16:18:11 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,-1) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 1114
2016-02-06 16:18:11 QUERY  : Query result: timestamp without time zone
2016-02-06 16:18:11 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=1114
2016-02-06 16:18:12 QUERY  : Query result: 1114
2016-02-06 16:18:12 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,-1) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 1114
2016-02-06 16:18:12 QUERY  : Query result: timestamp without time zone
2016-02-06 16:18:12 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=1114
2016-02-06 16:18:12 QUERY  : Query result: 1114
2016-02-06 16:18:12 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,-1) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 1114
2016-02-06 16:18:12 QUERY  : Query result: timestamp without time zone
2016-02-06 16:18:12 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=1114
2016-02-06 16:18:12 QUERY  : Query result: 1114
2016-02-06 16:18:12 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,-1) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 16
2016-02-06 16:18:12 QUERY  : Query result: boolean
2016-02-06 16:18:12 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=16
2016-02-06 16:18:12 QUERY  : Query result: 16
2016-02-06 16:18:12 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,-1) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 23
2016-02-06 16:18:12 QUERY  : Query result: integer
2016-02-06 16:18:12 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=23
2016-02-06 16:18:13 QUERY  : Query result: 23
2016-02-06 16:18:13 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,-1) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 23
2016-02-06 16:18:13 QUERY  : Query result: integer
2016-02-06 16:18:13 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=23
2016-02-06 16:18:13 QUERY  : Query result: 23
2016-02-06 16:18:13 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,-1) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 16
2016-02-06 16:18:13 QUERY  : Query result: boolean
2016-02-06 16:18:13 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=16
2016-02-06 16:18:13 QUERY  : Query result: 16
2016-02-06 16:18:13 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,-1) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 23
2016-02-06 16:18:13 QUERY  : Query result: integer
2016-02-06 16:18:13 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=23
2016-02-06 16:18:13 QUERY  : Query result: 23
2016-02-06 16:18:13 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,-1) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 23
2016-02-06 16:18:13 QUERY  : Query result: integer
2016-02-06 16:18:13 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=23
2016-02-06 16:18:14 QUERY  : Query result: 23
2016-02-06 16:18:14 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,-1) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 16
2016-02-06 16:18:14 QUERY  : Query result: boolean
2016-02-06 16:18:14 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=16
2016-02-06 16:18:14 QUERY  : Query result: 16
2016-02-06 16:18:14 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,-1) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 23
2016-02-06 16:18:14 QUERY  : Query result: integer
2016-02-06 16:18:14 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=23
2016-02-06 16:18:14 QUERY  : Query result: 23
2016-02-06 16:18:14 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,-1) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 1114
2016-02-06 16:18:15 QUERY  : Query result: timestamp without time zone
2016-02-06 16:18:15 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=1114
2016-02-06 16:18:15 QUERY  : Query result: 1114
2016-02-06 16:18:15 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,-1) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 23
2016-02-06 16:18:15 QUERY  : Query result: integer
2016-02-06 16:18:15 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=23
2016-02-06 16:18:16 QUERY  : Query result: 23
2016-02-06 16:18:16 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,-1) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 23
2016-02-06 16:18:16 QUERY  : Query result: integer
2016-02-06 16:18:16 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=23
2016-02-06 16:18:16 QUERY  : Query result: 23
2016-02-06 16:18:16 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,-1) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 23
2016-02-06 16:18:16 QUERY  : Query result: integer
2016-02-06 16:18:16 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=23
2016-02-06 16:18:16 QUERY  : Query result: 23
2016-02-06 16:18:16 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,-1) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 23
2016-02-06 16:18:16 QUERY  : Query result: integer
2016-02-06 16:18:16 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=23
2016-02-06 16:18:16 QUERY  : Query result: 23
2016-02-06 16:18:16 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,259) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 1043
2016-02-06 16:18:17 QUERY  : Query result: character varying(255)
2016-02-06 16:18:17 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=1043
2016-02-06 16:18:17 QUERY  : Query result: 1043
2016-02-06 16:18:17 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,-1) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 23
2016-02-06 16:18:17 QUERY  : Query result: integer
2016-02-06 16:18:17 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=23
2016-02-06 16:18:17 QUERY  : Query result: 23
2016-02-06 16:18:17 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,-1) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 16
2016-02-06 16:18:17 QUERY  : Query result: boolean
2016-02-06 16:18:17 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=16
2016-02-06 16:18:17 QUERY  : Query result: 16
2016-02-06 16:18:17 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,-1) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 23
2016-02-06 16:18:17 QUERY  : Query result: integer
2016-02-06 16:18:17 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=23
2016-02-06 16:18:18 QUERY  : Query result: 23
2016-02-06 16:18:18 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,-1) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 23
2016-02-06 16:18:18 QUERY  : Query result: integer
2016-02-06 16:18:18 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=23
2016-02-06 16:18:18 QUERY  : Query result: 23
2016-02-06 16:18:18 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,-1) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 23
2016-02-06 16:18:18 QUERY  : Query result: integer
2016-02-06 16:18:18 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=23
2016-02-06 16:18:18 QUERY  : Query result: 23
2016-02-06 16:18:18 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,-1) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 1114
2016-02-06 16:18:18 QUERY  : Query result: timestamp without time zone
2016-02-06 16:18:18 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=1114
2016-02-06 16:18:18 QUERY  : Query result: 1114
2016-02-06 16:18:18 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,-1) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 23
2016-02-06 16:18:18 QUERY  : Query result: integer
2016-02-06 16:18:18 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=23
2016-02-06 16:18:19 QUERY  : Query result: 23
2016-02-06 16:18:19 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,-1) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 16
2016-02-06 16:18:19 QUERY  : Query result: boolean
2016-02-06 16:18:19 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=16
2016-02-06 16:18:19 QUERY  : Query result: 16
2016-02-06 16:18:19 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,-1) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 16
2016-02-06 16:18:19 QUERY  : Query result: boolean
2016-02-06 16:18:19 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=16
2016-02-06 16:18:19 QUERY  : Query result: 16
2016-02-06 16:18:19 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,-1) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 1114
2016-02-06 16:18:19 QUERY  : Query result: timestamp without time zone
2016-02-06 16:18:19 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=1114
2016-02-06 16:18:19 QUERY  : Query result: 1114
2016-02-06 16:18:19 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,-1) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 20
2016-02-06 16:18:19 QUERY  : Query result: bigint
2016-02-06 16:18:19 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=20
2016-02-06 16:18:20 QUERY  : Query result: 20
2016-02-06 16:18:20 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,-1) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 16
2016-02-06 16:18:20 QUERY  : Query result: boolean
2016-02-06 16:18:20 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=16
2016-02-06 16:18:20 QUERY  : Query result: 16
2016-02-06 16:18:20 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT format_type(oid,-1) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 1114
2016-02-06 16:18:20 QUERY  : Query result: timestamp without time zone
2016-02-06 16:18:20 QUERY  : Scalar query (server): SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=1114
2016-02-06 16:18:20 QUERY  : Query result: 1114
```

Comment: Does it always hang?

Comment: @dezso any time I press F5 to re-run the query. is it enough for "always"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The extract from `pgadmin.log` shows that for each output column of the result, `pgadmin` executes two queries against the catalog, one to obtain the formatted name of the type from its `oid`, another to obtain a potential base type.

In your extract, if I'm counting right, the total number of such queries appears to be `106`.

From the ping time of `148 ms`, let's assume that the minimum time for a round-trip to the server is `148 ms`. So the minimum time taken by this set of queries would be `148 x 106 = 15688 ms`, or `15.6 s`

On the other hand, the command-line `psql` client doesn't do any of these queries, so it can be expected to have finished at least `15.6` seconds before pgadmin.

I'm not aware of any option in pgadmin to disable that, you may want to ask the developers or check if you have the newest version, but a question similar to yours  was asked last year on the mailing-list, and apparently got no response:

[Long query results rendering](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CACbBOUB06Gf9uWsHyHKhAgxK3M-6yAKnb_yj9zHXSn-c=HjV9A@mail.gmail.com) (in pgadmin-support archives).

It's a disappointing implementation detail in pgAdmin. It could get all results through a single query, with the list of types OIDs passed in an `IN(...)` construct or an array.
It could also cache these results and not even repeat queries on OIDs that it has already seen.